How to Avoid Privileged Docker Container to Write to Google Cloud Storage from Python?
Basic Goal
Training some machine learning model by pulling feature from a database and need to persist the model (tensorflow protobuf format) in Google cloud storage buckets for later serving. This is the very simple architecture.

Library Dependency
I am using Cloud storage fuse for interfacing with the Google cloud storage bucket and containerising the application in a docker image. This is how the relevant lines in the Dockerfile look like.
# The base image
ARG DISTRIBUTION=debian
FROM $DISTRIBUTION 
...
# Install cloud storage fuse 
export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.asc] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | tee /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.asc
apt-get --assume-yes update
apt-get --assume-yes --no-install-recommends install gcsfuse

All good, except, the container has to run with the privileged flag, which

Some runtimes may disallow, e.g. if I am using kubernetes?
I understand to be a security risk, although not sure why?

Question
But I want the gcsfuse as it provides a clean local-filesystem like interface to cloud, almost letting me forget that I am persisting the files in cloud, also makes it easy to swap out with different filesystems in future if necessary, providing ideal interface segregation.
So what's the way out? Is there any way to use to gcsfuse without the privileged mode, or somehow giving the container just enough permission to interface with the cloud storage?

@SaiChandiniRouthu did not have a chance to test it yet, but seems like a sensible solution. Upvoted it, will come back if needed after testing.
